# How to Improve Postgres performance on Big table

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I am trying to select some rows in postgres table having 300millions data
Here is my query

```
select "oid" from tableA
where "st" = 'A'  and "pid" = 'hb1'
 and "vid" in ('kd2532', 'kd2467', 'kd2567', 'kd2820', 'kd2944',
      'kd2809', 'kd2674', 'kd2816', 'kd4432', 'kd2660', 'MA0000011877',
      'MA0000012170', 'kd2613', 'kdc12075', 'kd2572', 'kd2521', 'kd2745',
      'kd2592', 'kd2692', 'kd4431', 'kd4433')
```

Its taking long time to execute

I have index on st, pid and vid columns and I did Analyze on table but there is no use

here is my Explain

```
"Gather  (cost=64242.39..6675878.02 rows=3896963 width=13)"
"  Workers Planned: 1"
"  Single Copy: true"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tableA  (cost=63242.39..6285181.72 rows=3896963 width=13)"
"        Recheck Cond: (((""vid"")::text = ANY ('{kd2532,kd2467,kd2567,kd2820,kd2944,kd2809,kd2674,kd2816,kd4432,kd2660,kdc11877,kdc12170,kd2613,kdc12075,kd2572,kd2521,kd2745,kd2592,kd2692,kd4431,kd4433}'::text[])) AND ((""pid"")::text = 'kd0089'::text) AND ((""st"")::text = 'A'::text))"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_name  (cost=0.00..62268.15 rows=3896963 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: (((""vid"")::text = ANY ('{kd2532,kd2467,kd2567,kd2820,kd2944,kd2809,kd2674,kd2816,kd4432,kd2660,kdc11877,kdc12170,kd2613,kdc12075,kd2572,kd2521,kd2745,kd2592,kd2692,kd4431,kd4433}'::text[])) AND ((""pid"")::text = 'kd0089'::text) AND ((""st"")::text = 'A'::text))"
```

And here is my explain analyze

```
"Gather  (cost=64242.39..6675878.02 rows=3896963 width=13) (actual time=4551.354..263819.428 rows=26181440 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 1"
"  Workers Launched: 1"
"  Single Copy: true"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tableA  (cost=63242.39..6285181.72 rows=3896963 width=13) (actual time=4544.571..242774.883 rows=26181440 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: (((""vid"")::text = ANY ('{kd2532,kd2467,kd2567,kd2820,kd2944,kd2809,kd2674,kd2816,kd4432,kd2660,kdc11877,kdc12170,kd2613,kdc12075,kd2572,kd2521,kd2745,kd2592,kd2692,kd4431,kd4433}'::text[])) AND ((""pid"")::text = 'kd0089'::text) AND ((""st"")::text = 'A'::text))"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_name  (cost=0.00..62268.15 rows=3896963 width=0) (actual time=3183.461..3183.462 rows=26181440 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (((""vid"")::text = ANY ('{kd2532,kd2467,kd2567,kd2820,kd2944,kd2809,kd2674,kd2816,kd4432,kd2660,kdc11877,kdc12170,kd2613,kdc12075,kd2572,kd2521,kd2745,kd2592,kd2692,kd4431,kd4433}'::text[])) AND ((""pid"")::text = 'kd0089'::text) AND ((""st"")::text = 'A'::text))"
"Planning Time: 0.319 ms"
"Execution Time: 265603.801 ms"
```

Here is my explain analyze verbose

```
"Gather  (cost=64242.39..6675878.02 rows=3896963 width=13) (actual time=5212.260..183691.470 rows=26181440 loops=1)"
"  Output: ""oid"""
"  Workers Planned: 1"
"  Workers Launched: 1"
"  Single Copy: true"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tableA  (cost=63242.39..6285181.72 rows=3896963 width=13) (actual time=5205.109..166780.456 rows=26181440 loops=1)"
"        Output: ""oid"""
"        Recheck Cond: (((tableA.""vid"")::text = ANY ('{kd2532,kd2467,kd2567,kd2820,kd2944,kd2809,kd2674,kd2816,kd4432,kd2660,kdc11877,kdc12170,kd2613,kdc12075,kd2572,kd2521,kd2745,kd2592,kd2692,kd4431,kd4433}'::text[])) AND ((tableA.""pid"")::text = 'kd0089'::text) AND ((tableA.""st"")::text = 'A'::text))"
"        Worker 0:  actual time=5205.109..166780.456 rows=26181440 loops=1"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_name (cost=0.00..62268.15 rows=3896963 width=0) (actual time=3845.546..3845.547 rows=26181440 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (((tableA.""vid"")::text = ANY ('{kd2532,kd2467,kd2567,kd2820,kd2944,kd2809,kd2674,kd2816,kd4432,kd2660,kdc11877,kdc12170,kd2613,kdc12075,kd2572,kd2521,kd2745,kd2592,kd2692,kd4431,kd4433}'::text[])) AND ((tableA.""pid"")::text = 'kd0089'::text) AND ((tableA.""st"")::text = 'A'::text))"
"              Worker 0:  actual time=3845.546..3845.547 rows=26181440 loops=1"
"Planning Time: 0.299 ms"
"Execution Time: 185388.678 ms"
```

explain (analyze,buffers)

```
"Gather  (cost=64242.39..6675878.02 rows=3896963 width=13) (actual time=5285.960..273164.726 rows=26181440 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 1"
"  Workers Launched: 1"
"  Single Copy: true"
"  Buffers: shared hit=820490 read=1662881"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tableA  (cost=63242.39..6285181.72 rows=3896963 width=13) (actual time=5279.352..250935.123 rows=26181440 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: (((""vid"")::text = ANY ('{kd2532,kd2467,kd2567,kd2820,kd2944,kd2809,kd2674,kd2816,kd4432,kd2660,kdc11877,kdc12170,kd2613,kdc12075,kd2572,kd2521,kd2745,kd2592,kd2692,kd4431,kd4433}'::text[])) AND ((""pid"")::text = 'kd0089'::text) AND ((""st"")::text = 'A'::text))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=820490 read=1662881"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_name  (cost=0.00..62268.15 rows=3896963 width=0) (actual time=4036.831..4036.832 rows=26181440 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (((""vid"")::text = ANY ('{kd2532,kd2467,kd2567,kd2820,kd2944,kd2809,kd2674,kd2816,kd4432,kd2660,kdc11877,kdc12170,kd2613,kdc12075,kd2572,kd2521,kd2745,kd2592,kd2692,kd4431,kd4433}'::text[])) AND ((""pid"")::text = 'kd0089'::text) AND ((""st"")::text = 'A'::text))"
"              Buffers: shared hit=17197 read=5614"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=200 read=13"
"Planning Time: 21.060 ms"
"Execution Time: 275229.350 ms"
```

let me know how to over come this issue

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your execution plan, but a *Bitmap Heap Scan* on 4M rows will definitively take a considerable time. `BUFFERS` option will show further detail. Check the performance (parallel) *sequential scan*, this could be (while reading more than 1% of the data) comparable or even better. If this is not acceptable you'll have to introduce some sort of partitioning to see better results.

Comment: Could you share the DDL for your index? You could use  " INCLUDE (oid); " when creating the index, that gives the planner the option to use an index only scan, avoiding an additional read of the table.

Comment: here is my index DDL statement " CREATE INDEX  idx_name  ON tableA USING btree
    ("vid" , "pid" , "st" )"

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, pg returns 26m rows, and the timing for reading all the pages seems okay-ish, depending on the hardware, of course, and your configuration like shared buffers and work memory.

You can however try adding `oid` to your indices, hoping this query can utilise [Index Only Scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/indexes-index-only-scans.html) and will be fulfilled in seconds and not minutes.

Something along those lines:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON tableA USING btree (vid, pid, st) INCLUDE (oid)
```

Comment: Other possible ways to speed this up: 1) increase `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` 2) `CLUSTER tablea USING ix_propertyvalueid;`

Comment: my max_parallel_workers_pergather is 64

Comment: 2nd point I didn't get you

Comment: @user21741847 see the linked doc, you have to have an index with all the referenced fields included in it + index must be of a type that supports index only scans. Given your query, that index would be `(oid, pid, st, vid)`

Comment: `oid` should not be the first column in the index since it is not a search term. Frank Heikens' suggestion to add `INCLUDE (oid)` to the index definition is a correct approach. It would also be acceptable to add `oid` to the end of the indexed columns since it's not a unique index.

Comment: Oh that's right, the `oid` should be the last one or `INCLUDE`ed